# Turning off TeX mode for exponent notation of tick labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to turn off the TeX rendering for the x- and y-ticklabels (logarithmic y-scale). I followed the suggestion of [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) provided in [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8436) issue which works for my x-axis but not for the exponent notation on the y-axis.

In the below figure, as you can notice, the TeX rendering is *turned off* for x-ticklabels but it is still *turned on*  for the y-ticklabels.

**Question**: How can I turn off the TeX mode for y-ticklabels as well in my case **maintaining** the label notation as 10^-n? There may be a dupe but I couldn't easily find it.

---

Following is a reproducible code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))

# Define data
x = range(100)
y = np.logspace(-12, 0, 100)

# Plot data and label axis
plt.semilogy(x, y)
plt.xlabel('x-label', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('y-label', fontsize=20)
plt.xlim(0, 100)
plt.ylim(1e-12, 1)

# Increase fontsize for ticklabels for better identification
for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(16) 
for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(16)   

# Turn off the TeX rendering for x and y-ticklabels
ax.xaxis.get_major_formatter()._usetex = False
ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter()._usetex = False # This does not work

plt.show()
```

The above code generates the following plot:

[image]

My `python` and `matplotlib` versions are

```
import sys
import matplotlib

print (sys.version)
# 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| 

print (matplotlib.__version__)
# 2.2.2
```

Comment: You are using tex. How would a tex be able to create something like $10^{2}$ outside of mathmode? Is that even possible?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Hmm, good point. Off the top of my head, I am not aware of generating $10^{2}$ without mathmode. Any workaround from your experience to achieve the y-ticklabels in the same font style as x-ticklabels in the figure?

Comment: In that case the problem boils down to using the same tex font for normal text as for mathmode. So maybe something like [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/userdemo/pgf_texsystem_sgskip.html).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks for the link. I actually don't know the fontname of my x-label, y-label and x-ticks. It looks good to me that's why I want to live with it. While replacing the data in the link with my logarithmic scale data, I get rid of MathMode on y-ticklabels but I am not sure if I can adapt the linked answer to get the font I have currently in my figure's x-ticklabels

Comment: I think in general you can't. Not every font that is available in tex has a corresponding math mode font. So I guess the idea is to find a font that has a corresponding math font available and use that instead. Googling for "latex sans serif font math mode" would bring up some results, e.g. [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24035/typeset-mathematical-symbols-also-in-sans-serif-font).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks a lot. I will give it a try and see how the aesthetics look like.